# Adding a new row/column with a single filled element containing a sum with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dataframe that looks like the excel image below. I would like to add a single cell on the bottom corner that contains the sum. I'm certain that someone else has asked this question but I can't seem to find the answer. If anyone could help me with the code needed to place that sum item in the same location as below or direct me to a similar question I'd greatly appreciate it. I have a feeling that I'm not searching for the right term but I don't know what that term would be. Thanks in advance!

[image: The current dataset]

[image: The desired output]

Comment: FWIW, pandas is probably not the best tool for this. Creating a mostly empty column and a mostly empty row to offset a single value visually is not a primary use case for a DataFrame.

Comment: you can create a sum, but that would be stored in a variable in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the best way to use a pandas DataFrame but if you need to do it anyway then here is one way you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Jerry', 'Tom', 'Larry', 'Jill'],
                   'B': [5, 8, 12, 4]})

# Add empty line at the bottom
df.loc[len(df)] = [pd.NA] * len(df.columns)

# Add a column containing the sum
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [pd.NA] * (len(df)-1) + [df.B.sum()]})
df.join(df2)
```

Result:

```
|A    |B   |C   |
|-----|----|----|
|Jerry|5   |<NA>|
|Tom  |8   |<NA>|
|Larry|12  |<NA>|
|Jill |4   |<NA>|
|NaN  |<NA>|29  |
```

Again this is not how you should use DataFrames. If you want to display your data you maybe want to try using plotly tables instead.

Comment: this is a good answer given the question.  need to protect yourself from the downvotes with the caveat that this is not the use case of a df.